# message.getContent() returns instance of String not a Multipart object

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, attachment, multipart, pop3

I am new to java mail and I have been struggling for a while now trying to download attachments from a mail server. I am using java mail 1.5.5 I have been searching the internet on how to connect to a mail server and download emails and attachments and I have this code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);

store = session.getStore();
store.connect("my.mail.server", "myusername", "mypassword");
folder = store.getDefaultFolder().getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();

for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");
    Message msg = messages[i];

    System.out.println(msg.getContent().getClass());
    System.out.println(msg.getDisposition());
    System.out.println(msg.getFileName());
    System.out.println(msg.getContentType());
    System.out.println(msg.getFrom());
    System.out.println(msg.getReceivedDate());
    System.out.println(msg.getReplyTo());
    System.out.println(msg.getSentDate());
}
```

and the result of this code is:

```
content:      class java.lang.String
disposition:  null
fileName:     null
contentType:  text/plain
from:         null
receivedDate: null
replyTo:      null
sendDate:     null
```

I am not sure, but shouldn't I receive at least the "from" or "sendDate" of the message? Why are those fields null? What am I doing wrong?

The content of the message is a type of `String`.

Please tell me where I am doing wrong, Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is the debugging log:

```
Loading javamail.default.providers from jar:file:/D:/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/my_web/WEB-INF/lib/javax.mail-1.5.5.jar!/META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imap, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imaps, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtp, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtps, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3s, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
Loading javamail.default.providers from jar:file:/D:/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/my_web/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.7.jar!/META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imap, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=imaps, className=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtp, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=smtps, className=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: loading new provider protocol=pop3s, className=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore, vendor=Oracle, version=null
DEBUG: getProvider() returning provider protocol=pop3; type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@7e56e2bd; class=com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store; vendor=Oracle
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disabletop: true
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.enable: true
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.starttls.required: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "mail.mymail.am", port 110, isSSL false
+OK Dovecot ready.
CAPA
+OK
CAPA
TOP
UIDL
RESP-CODES
PIPELINING
AUTH-RESP-CODE
STLS
USER
SASL PLAIN LOGIN
.
DEBUG POP3: PIPELINING enabled
STLS
+OK Begin TLS negotiation now.
CAPA
+OK
CAPA
TOP
UIDL
RESP-CODES
PIPELINING
AUTH-RESP-CODE
USER
SASL PLAIN LOGIN
.
DEBUG POP3: authentication command trace suppressed
DEBUG POP3: authentication command succeeded
STAT
+OK 73 5815632
```

Comment: Do you know the actual contents of the inbox you're reading? Does the number of messages in the inbox match the length of the `messages` array?  Do ALL the messages look the same?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I know exactly what are the contents, and yes, the number of messages match the length of the messages array, they all look the same when I try to print the `msg.getContent()`.

Comment: This is the starting lines of the messages content:

`This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_0042_01D060A9.DEB81590
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`

Comment: You should examine the network traffic during the transaction, with Wireshark, to see what is actually being sent back and forth.

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  What POP3 server are you using?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  Note that there's lots of other help and examples in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).

Comment: @BillShannon I am using `mail-1.4.7` version, if you want I can show you the whole console of the debugging process, and I know about the java mail api, I have tried everything they are suggesting, still... I am getting null on everything.

Comment: Yes, post the debug output.  And consider upgrading to the latest version - [JavaMail 1.5.5](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: @BillShannon I have updated the question with more info, btw, I upgraded the java mail version to 1.5.5 and I still get the same result.

Comment: @Shahe : Is it possible if you put the message(probably its source) here? and I think it would be also helpful if you tell us how you send the message in the first place.

Comment: @kucing_terbang The message was sent using Microsoft Outlook 2013.

Comment: @Shahe : OK, then how about the source of the message? because, I assume that some attribute could be missing from the email.

Comment: @kucing_terbang What do you mean by source of the message? I am sorry I didn't get it

Comment: @Shahe : Sorry, I mean the message header. Usually they have some attribute to tell which the email is come from and stuff like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103470/discussion-between-shahe-and-kucing-terbang).

Comment: @kucing_terbang I found something, my code is working just fine when I try to run it in a separate java project that has just the java mail 1.4.7 jar, but when I run it in my web application it is not working, do you think that there is a conflict in my application?

Comment: There must be more in your debug log since what you've posted doesn't show any attempt to read any messages from the server.

Comment: @BillShannon Could the problem come from the tomcat configuration? I mean I am able to send emails using SMTP protocol, but unable to receive them using pop3 or imap, as I said, I tried to run my code from an standalone java project and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Your debug log shows that you're connecting and authenticating successfully.  If there's more to the debug log, post it.  If the debug log stops there, you need to figure out what's going wrong that's either preventing the debug log output from being captured, or causing JavaMail to appear to function but without any debug output.  It's not obvious how Tomcat configuration would effect either of these.  More likely is some firewall or anti-virus program causing problems.

Comment: @BillShannon I fixed my problem by adding the dependency `geronimo-javamail-spec-1.4` "provided" in my pom.xml, now everything works just fine, Thank you

Comment: I suspect you have both the official JavaMail implementation and the Geronimo implementation available to your program.  I recommend removing the Geronimo version and using the [official JavaMail version](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).